# Association a buscador rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Tengo una aplicación de remisiones, tengo un maestro de detalle donde agrego los productos, los tengo el select con una association,la lista se me hizo muy grande y ahora quiero que sea un buscador, estoy tratando de convertirlo con jquery y un tutorial que eh encontrado(www.rubyplus.com/articles/3701).

Tengo un problema principal y es que mi select lo saco de una tabla check que contiene(referencia y descripcion) y un model("partial") que conecto a remisiones que es atris, que contiene(lote,cantidad y unidad),estos 5 elementos forman un atributo de remisiones, es decir entre check y atri esta la association.

Mi partial de atris:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="col-md-10" style = "float: left">
    <%= f.association :check, label: "Productos" %>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-2" style = "float: left">
    <h5><%= f.input :lote %></h5>
  </div>
    <div class=" col-md-6" style = "float: left">
      <h5><%= f.input :cantidad %></h5>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-6" style = "float: left">
      <h5><%= f.input :unidad, :input_html => { :value => 'UND' }%></h5>
    </div>

    <div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association  "X",f,class:"btn btn-outline-danger" %>
      </div>
      <hr>
</div>
```

Cambie la association creando un metodo asi:

```
  <div class="col-md-10" style = "float: left">
    <%= f.label :check_name, label: "Productos" %>
  </div>
```

Mi model de atris :

```
def check_name
  check.try(:referencia,:descripcion)
end

def check_name=(name)
  self.check = check.find_by(name: name) if name.present?
end
```

Hasta ahi voy en el tutorial y me sale erro de below creo que tiene que ver con las conexiones pero ya las revise y creo que estan bien.
Model remision :

```
has_many :atris, :dependent => :destroy
```

Model atris :

```
belongs_to :check
```

Model check :

```
has_many :atris
```

Pareciera que lo tengo trocado pero no, mi logica es que remision conecte con atris ya que es el partial agregado y atris que conecte con check, asi me funciono bien el select.
Y mi llave foranea :

```
  add_reference :atrichecks, :checkatri, foreign_key: true
```

Mi show de remision :

```
<% @remision.atris.each do |atri|%>
<p>
<strong>Referencia :</strong><%=atri.check.try(:referencia)%>
<strong>Descripcion :</strong><%=atri.check.try(:descripcion)%>
<strong>Lote :</strong><%=atri.lote%>
<strong>Cantidad :</strong><%=atri.cantidad%>
<strong>Unidad :</strong><%=atri.unidad%></p>
<%end%>
```

remisions.js

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#remision_atri_check_name').autocomplete({
    source: ['apple', 'apricot', 'avocado', 'appTv', 'armario']
  });
});
```

El error se presenta al momento de guardar o de generar la remision en el campo ":check_name", no me toma lo que escribo, se recarga la pagina, me borra lo que escribi en ese unico campo, y en la parte de arriba me da una alerta que dice

> "PLEASE REVIEW THE PROBLEMS BELOW".

En este punto tendria que poder guardarlos correctamente o por lo menos desplegar el menu que tengo definido con jQuery, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hola null null, bienvenido a S.O. en español. ¿cuál es el error específico que estás recibiendo? ¿puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta? que siento que agregaste demasiada información, pero no la relacionada específicamente con tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Mi problema es que deberia estar guardando la informacion sumistrada en el campo o por lo menos desplegar el menu que tengo definido con jQuery

Comment: En una parte de tu pregunta pusiste `me sale erro de below`. No se a que te refieres con eso, pero me imagino que quieres decir que te está arrojando un error. A eso me refiero, si te sale un error, agrégalo a la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Hola @AlterLagos el error se presenta al momento de guardar o de generar la remision en el campo ":check_name", no me toma lo que escribo, se recarga la pagina, me borra lo que escribi en ese unico campo, y en la parte de arriba me da una alerta que dice "PLEASE REVIEW THE PROBLEMS BELOW". Saludos.

Comment: Ok, si te sale ese mensaje, creo que podrías agregar el log de tu consola cuando creas tu registro, también el código relevante de tu controlador (create y tus strong_params). Además, solo por términos de depuración, podrías probar a cambiar el `.save` por `.save!` para que te arroje un error más específico de lo que está causando problemas, luego lo vuelves a dejar como `.save`. A ver si eso da más pistas. Saludos